# making a single script wrapping 3 python codes

Tags: python

I have 3 python codes which I want to call one after another automatically  so that they result in the final in s single call.
How do I wrap these codes into single script? codes are `model-multiple.py`, `align2d.py`, `model-single.py`.

model-multiple.py   is

```
from modeller import *              # Load standard Modeller classes
from modeller.automodel import *    # Load the automodel class

log.verbose()    # request verbose output
env = environ()  # create a new MODELLER environment to build this model in


env.io.atom_files_directory = ['.', '../atom_files']

a = automodel(env,
alnfile  = '3NTD_align.ali', # alignment filename
knowns   = ('3NTDA'),    
sequence = 'target',        # code of the target
assess_methods=(assess.DOPE, assess.GA341,assess.normalized_dope))
a.starting_model= 1                 # index of the first model
a.ending_model  = 1              # index of the last model
                                    # (determines how many models to calculate)
a.make()                            # do the actual homology modeling
```

Comment: Those are not "python codes", they're Python (program) files. A code is a function mapping content and representation in an unobvious way.

Comment: @phihag: the word "code" has more than one meaning in English

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. The quick-and-dirty way: just call them one after another in a shell script or in a Python script (using `system` or `subprocess.Popen`)
2. Make them do their work in some function, import them into a single script and invoke each module's "do work" function

Answer (score 2):

If all three scripts are similar to your example, you can use the follow Python script to run them one after the other:

```
__import__('model-multiple')
import align2d
__import__('model-single')
```

`__import__` is required because hyphens(-) are illegal in import names.  If you're willing to rename the scripts:

```
import model_multiple
import align2d
import model_single
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider organizing your scripts in a way that is convenient for calling both from other scrips and directly. The general pattern is:

```
def main():
    # do all the work
if __name__ = '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```